# Toggle text, on a checkbox input change

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

I searched and tried a lot of codes & samples but I didn't get to my point.
I have 3 `checkbox` inputs and 3 `labels` after each, and a `div` including a `<p>` tag.
I want when I check each `checkbox`, the next label text to be copied in the `<p>` tag, and when I uncheck it, remove the text in `<p>` tag. I mean toggling the label text inside the `<p>` tag by changing the inputs.

my HTML code :

```
<div class="chbxs">
    <input type="checkbox" name="country" id="Iran" rel="Iran" />
    <label for="Iran">Mashad,Tehran</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="country" id="England" rel="England" />
    <label for="England">London,Manchester</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="country" id="USA" rel="USA" />
    <label for="USA">California,NewYork</label>
</div>
<div class="countries">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

my jquery code :

```
$('.chbxs input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var chkdChkbox = $(this).next('label').text();
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        $('.countries > p').append('<span>' + chkdChkbox + '</span>');
    }
    else {
        $('.countries > p').children('span').remove();
    }
});
```

The problem is that if I uncheck an input, all spans will be removed. How can I fix this? Tank you so much.
P.S: I also want to separate texts from each other by a comma.

Comment: Give an `id` or `class` to the span. `id` would be better if there would be only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to amend the logic so that the text is generated taking into account all the `checkboxes` which are checked, not the one which was clicked on. Try this:

```
var setCountryText = function() {
    var $p = $('.countries > p').empty();
    $('.chbxs :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        $p.append('<span>' + $(this).next('label').text() + '</span>');
    });
}

$('.chbxs input[type="checkbox"]').click(setCountryText);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jR9G2/2/)

Comment: thank you so much, one more thing please. I want to separate them with comma. if I use `$p.append('<span>' + $(this).next('label').text() + '</span>',',')` then it will put comma after each one. I just want the comma to be added when another text comes after. If it becomes complicated just let it go, it's not so important

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $contriesp = $('.countries > p');
$('.chbxs input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var $chk = $(this), rel = $chk.attr('rel');
    if (this.checked) {
        $('<span />', {
            html: $chk.next('label').text()
        }).appendTo($contriesp).attr('rel', rel)
    } else {
        $contriesp.children('span[rel="' + rel + '"]').remove();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N9Ucn/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('.chbxs input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        var chkdChkbox = $(this).next('label').text();
        var chkdChkboxId = $(this).attr("id");
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
            $('.countries > p').append('<span id="country_'+chkdChkboxId +'">' + chkdChkbox + '</span>');
        }
        else {
            $('.countries > p').children('#country_'+chkdChkboxId).remove();
        }
    });
```